# The C# project is targeting NETFramework Version=v4.7.1, which is not installed on this machine

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-2019

I've just downloaded Unity 2020.1.0f1 and included Visual Studio Community 2019 in the options. When I open C# files within Unity, each file I open loads on a new instance of VS2019 (instead of loading in another tab of the same instance), and shows the window below:

[image]

I went to Visual Studio Installer and made sure to install not only Developer Tools 4.7.1, but all existent versions (sorry for the image not in english but it's understandable):

[image]

The error keeps appearing everytime I open a C# file. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just solved! I'll show the steps I took.

---

`1` First, in VS2019, right click on the Project and click in **Manage NuGet Packages**:

[image]

`2` Click in Browse and search for `NETFramework`. Look for the version that is right for you. In my case, it was this one (`Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies.net471`):

[image]

`3` Reload the project. In my case, the boring window stopped appearing and the files are opening in new tabs of the same VS2019 instance, instead of opening a new instance of VS2019 for each file.

Answer (score 7):

You can install this targeting frameworks using the visual studio installer.

Visual Studio Installer -> Modify -> Individual Components -> Select the needed .NET Framework targeting pack versions

[image: install components]

Reference: http://dahlindevelopment.com/blog/september-2018/the-web-project-is-targeting-netframework,-version/

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio moved to Package Manager in 2020.1

Comment: Well, I didn't know that, but anyway, does it mean that Visual Studio Installer installs the developer tools in a random or useless place?

Comment: I had problems like this when VS recognised new files as "additional files", but not part of "Assembly-CSharp", but restarting Unity fixed problems. My Unity 2020.1 hasn't got this kind of problems.